# Android layout xml: difference "app:" and "<view_name>:"

Tags: android, android-layout

Using either of this prefixes gives the same result:

```
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
```

Are these only synonyms? And if so, why do both variants exist?

**EDIT**

As `Doomsknight` said in the comments it only happens to do the same when the namespace is exactly the same (which makes sense).

However I still don't understand where the difference between those prefixes lies.

Comment: you would have to post a full xml example. the namespaces are usually defined in the top view. `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. My guess is that you have either defined both as the same thing, or that they have an overlap

Comment: Yeah thats true if I change it it won't do anything! Thanks! Should put that as Edit. Though there still has to be a reason why both exists. I am just curious.

Comment: If they are both the same, you can delete one. You can literally call them what ever you want. e.g. `minions`, `bobmarley`. its just a custom name space, pointing to the schema defined. There is no point defining the same schema twice. Though it does no harm

Comment: There is also commonly an overlap between the support library and android, as it provides backwards compatibility attributes to some systems that don't support the android attributes.